# Majority vote algorithm in Weka.classifiers.meta.vote

Tags: weka

What is the majority vote algorithm used in Weka. I tried to figure out its code but could not understand it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Weka you can select multiple classifiers to be used in `Weka.classifiers.meta.vote`. If you select `Majority Voting` as `combinationRule` (which only works with `nominal` classes), then each of these classifiers will predict a nominal class label for a test sample. The label which was predicted the most will then be selected as output of the `vote` classifier.

For example. You select the following classifiers to be used: `trees.J48`, `bayes.NaiveBayes` and `functions.LibSVM` to predict the weather, which can be labelled `bad`, `normal` or `good`. Given a new test sample, these are their predictions:

```
J48        - bad
NaiveBayes - good
LibSVM     - good
```

The results in the following *votes* for each possible label:

```
bad    - 1
normal - 0
good   - 2
```

So Weka's `vote` classifier will select `good` as label for the test sample, because it has the most votes amongst all three classifiers.

**--Edit--**

The function `distributionForInstanceMajorityVoting` in the [source code](https://svn.scms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.java) of Weka's `Vote` class shows you how the majority voting is implemented. I added the function below. Here is a description of what it does:

The code works pretty much as I explained above. All nominal classes of the test instance are loaded into `votes`. Each classifier classifies the instance and the label with the highest probability gets a *vote*. If multiple labels have the same probability then all these labels receive a vote. Once all classifiers have cast there vote, the label with the most votes is selected as *the* label for the test instance. If multiple labels have the same amount of votes, then one of these labels will randomly be selected.

```java
protected double[] distributionForInstanceMajorityVoting(Instance instance) throws Exception {

  double[] probs = new double[instance.classAttribute().numValues()];
  double[] votes = new double[probs.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < m_Classifiers.length; i++) {
    probs = getClassifier(i).distributionForInstance(instance);
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<probs.length; j++) {
      if(probs[j] > probs[maxIndex])
        maxIndex = j;
    }

    // Consider the cases when multiple classes happen to have the same probability
    for (int j=0; j<probs.length; j++) {
      if (probs[j] == probs[maxIndex])
        votes[j]++;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < m_preBuiltClassifiers.size(); i++) {
    probs = m_preBuiltClassifiers.get(i).distributionForInstance(instance);
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j<probs.length; j++) {
      if(probs[j] > probs[maxIndex])
        maxIndex = j;
    }

    // Consider the cases when multiple classes happen to have the same probability
    for (int j=0; j<probs.length; j++) {
      if (probs[j] == probs[maxIndex])
        votes[j]++;
    }
  }

  int tmpMajorityIndex = 0;
  for (int k = 1; k < votes.length; k++) {
    if (votes[k] > votes[tmpMajorityIndex])
      tmpMajorityIndex = k;
  }

  // Consider the cases when multiple classes receive the same amount of votes
  Vector<Integer> majorityIndexes = new Vector<Integer>();
  for (int k = 0; k < votes.length; k++) {
    if (votes[k] == votes[tmpMajorityIndex])
      majorityIndexes.add(k);
   }

  // Resolve the ties according to a uniform random distribution
  int majorityIndex = majorityIndexes.get(m_Random.nextInt(majorityIndexes.size()));

  //set probs to 0
  probs = new double[probs.length];

  probs[majorityIndex] = 1; //the class that have been voted the most receives 1

  return probs;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I used some Weka classifiers and would like to fuse their results with other classifier from outside Weka. So, I would like to fuse the results instead of fusing the classifiers. I think of re implementing the portion of the Vote class to suit my need but face some difficulty. Any other idea?

Comment: It sounds like a good idea to call Weka from the command line. You can then individually train each Weka classifier (without using `meta.vote` and your non-Weka classifiers and then invoke each of them to predict a label. From there on you can implement majority voting yourself or use some other metric to combine the individual results.

Comment: That is my point, I have used Boyer-Moore algorithm for majority voting and compared the result with Weka's result, I got different results. Where could I found details about the voting algorithm used in Weka.  Thanking you.

Comment: I expanded my answer with Weka's code for majority voting and explained it. I'm not sure what you mean when you say _I have used Boyer-Moore algorithm for majority voting_. Are you using Boyer-Moore's algorithm and you want to combine that with majority voting? Could you explain in detail what you want to do?

Comment: @Sicco How can i get the weka.classifiers.meta.Vote return probabilities for classes? When i call distributionForInstance on weka.classifiers.meta.Vote i dont get soft probabilities for different classes (ex: i get [0, 0, 1] for 3 class). And it happens irrespective of which voting rule i choose. I have a dataset with some class imbalance. So i train three random-forest/svm/your-favourite classifiers on randomly undersampled balanced subsets (using SpreadSubSample) and fuse their decisions using voting classifier. And i really want the probability estimates for different classes. Any thoughts?